# SQL server configuration manager is not present in windows 10

Tags: windows

I have installed sql server 2012 express on windows 10 machine and sql server configuration manager is not present in c:\windows\system32. Any tip where it could be ?

Comment: Did you enable .net3.5 before install sql?

Comment: @Drifter104 Wouldn't this fail the pre-installation validation check?

Comment: @Reaces I think your answer is prob more likely but I managed to install full sql 2012 without .net3.5 I was missing the tools

Comment: @Drifter104 This is possible if you installed .net3.5, removed it, but the registry was not updated. If this happens again, try checking the registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\1033\SP`. It is the key that is checked during the installation of SQL Server.

Comment: If nothing works and you suspect that some registry cleaner program that you ran cleaned up the entries, then run the repair utility and in that, the shared features. I got it back. You should too.

Answer (score 2):

On a workstation running windows 8, 8.1 or 10 the location of the `SQLServerManager11.msc` is not the same as on a server (where it is located in the system32 folder).

For your workstation you can follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-not-found).

> - The newer Microsoft SQL Server Configuration Manager is a snap-in for    the Microsoft Management Console program.
> - It  is not a stand-alone    program as used in the previous versions of Microsoft Windows    operating systems,
> - SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn’t appear as    an application when running Windows 8.
> - To open SQL Server    Configuration Manager, in the Search charm, under Apps, type:
>
>   `SQLServerManager11.msc` (for SQL Server 2012) or
>
>   `SQLServerManager10.msc` for (SQL Server 2008), and then press
>     Enter.